# How to plot a surface with JFreeChart?

Tags: java, scala, charts, jfreechart

I'd like to be able to set a colour of every point (addressed by x&y, where x is a DateTime (of joda-time, actually) and y is a double) on a chart to represent a z=f(x,y) value. Is it possible with JFreeChart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood your needs correctly I think you want to use an XYPlot with an XYBlockRenderer.
Quoting the docs:

> A renderer that represents data from an XYZDataset by drawing a color block at each (x, y) point, where the color is a function of the z-value from the dataset

Check the sample image in the docs for XYBlockRenderer: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBlockRenderer.html

Comment: Thank you for a perfect-right answer. To be honest, I am pleasantly surprised there is one.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend http://www.jzy3d.org

Here are some example charts: http://www.jzy3d.org/gallery.php

And example code to plot a surface: https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/tree/master/jzy3d-tutorials

Comment: Thanks, a cool toolkit to know about. I am going to make use of it later.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I remember that's not possible by default. You can set only one color for every plotted series. However, I think it's possible to extend AbstractRenderer and achieve what you need.

Of course there is possibility that I'm mistaking. Dont remember for sure. :P